# How to change color of keys in KeyboardView Class in custom Android keyboard?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am working on a Custom Keyboard App. I need to set different themes for keys or background color in KeyboardView class and get key color at onCreateInputView() in SoftKeyboard extends InputMethodService Class.

However I am not getting how to get particular key according to keycode so I can change color or background of particular key.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  Supplying code of what you have tried will help you get help.

Comment: i have set to input.xml and input1.xml

Comment: i need to get keycode at run time i.e different key color  i have used three input.xml,input1.xml,input2.xml if input.xml inflate than keycolor will be green,blue combination if input1.xml inflate keys background color will red and orange ..similar for input2.xml so i am no getting how to this

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On any diffrent input layout use android:keyBackground=".."

example:

input.xml:

```
<com.example.KeyboardView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/keyboard"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:keyBackground="@drawable/blue_key"
        />
```

input1.xml:

```
<com.example.KeyboardView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/keyboard"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:keyBackground="@drawable/red_key"
            />
```

then on OnCreateInputView method:

```
@Override public View onCreateInputView() {
    if(theme == 1)
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.xml.input , null);
    else
        mInputView = (KeyboardView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.xml.input1 , null);
    mInputView.setOnKeyboardActionListener( this);
    mInputView.setKeyboard(mQwertyKeyboard);
    mComposing.setLength(0);
    return mInputView;
}
```

and on the end of the method onStartInput add this:

```
setInputView(onCreateInputView());
```

If you've already done it and what you need is to set a different background to special keys. Maybe the solution to my problem that I wrote will help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18354298/2683898

Good Luck! :)

Comment: Also, the background does not have to be a drawable.  It can it be a color resource as well.

Comment: this code is for change color of keyboard background not keyboardtextcolor.want to change color programmatically