# Is it possible to change custom keyboard key color?

Tags: android, background, keyboard, key

Is it possible to change custom keyboard key color ?? when I press on for example number 5 and stays that way with the new color until I delete the number 5 from edit text ???? i searched all the net and didn't find anything that you can change a specific key when pressing it ..!

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18286164/how-to-change-color-of-keys-in-keyboardview-class-in-custom-keyboard-android

Comment: i dont want to change the whole keyboard just the keys that i pressed and i tried this two things in the refer. it wont do what i need i want to stay the red color on the key when i press on it and release it 
blue---->clicked--->its now red